# how to map spring-data-rest JSON response with its object using RestTEmplate

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I am having the spring-data-rest application which was exposed with REST APIs. I am using this API to construct web applications. But I am unable to convert this API response into the POJO for ease of use. I am having the response as follows

```
    {
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons{&sort,page,size}", 
      "templated" : true
    },
    "next" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons?page=1&size=5{&sort}", 
      "templated" : true
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "person": {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "John"
    }
  },
  "page" : { 
    "size" : 5,
    "totalElements" : 50,
    "totalPages" : 10,
    "number" : 0
  }
}

restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Person.class);
```

this restTemplate throws me following error

```
    22:50:10.377 [http-bio-8080-exec-28] DEBUG c.o.x.o.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor - Error calling method through OGNL: object: [com.foo.supply.actions.ViewPersonsAction@9756ac3] method: [viewPersons] args: [[]]
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "_embedded" (Class com.foo.support.model.Person), not marked as ignorable 
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@d4aff35; line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.foo.support.model.Person["_embedded"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "_embedded" (Class com.foo.support.model.Person), not marked as ignorable 
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@d4aff35; line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.foo.support.model.Person["_embedded"])
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:127) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:153) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:81) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:446) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199) ~[spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
```

Person.java

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // getters and setters
}
```

How to get the Person object from response? I don't want to include _embedded field in my Persion class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of the rest response is not `Person.class` - it is `PagedResources<Person>`.

In order to use `RestTemplate` with a generic type you could use the following:

```
    PagedResources<Person> = restTemplate.exchange(
                    uri,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    null,
                    new ParametrizedReturnType()).getBody();

private static final class ParametrizedReturnType extends TypeReferences.PagedResourcesType<Person> {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my PagedResource type is dynamic. That is it may be Person or Employee or Visitor. I don't want to declare separate class for all of these. Because the response may be PagedResource<T> or Resource<T>